# Generar consulta que contenga campos vacíos

Tags: sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| users                                             |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | firstname | lastname | email                 |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | David     | Youssef  | david@youssef.com     |
|  2 | Guadalupe | Youssef  | guadalupe@youssef.com |
|  3 | Miguel    | Youssef  | miguel@youssef.com    |
|  4 | Facundo   | Youssef  | facundo@youssef,com   |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------------+

+----------------------+
| users_info_fields    |
+----+-----------------+
| id | field           |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | dni             |
|  2 | provincia       |
|  3 | establecimiento |
+----+-----------------+

+----------------------------------+
| users_info_data                  |
+----+--------+---------+----------+
| id | userid | fieldid | data     |
+----+--------+---------+----------+
|  1 |      1 |       1 | 11111111 |
|  2 |      1 |       2 | Tucuman  |
|  3 |      1 |       3 | UTN      |
|  4 |      2 |       1 | 22222222 |
|  5 |      2 |       2 | San Juan |
|  6 |      2 |       3 | EAS      |
|  7 |      4 |       1 | 444444   |
|  8 |      4 |       3 | ROSSO    |
|  9 |      3 |       1 | 33333333 |
+----+--------+---------+----------+
```

Y quiero hacer una consulta que me de el siguiente resultado:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| apellido | nombre    | DNI      | Provincia | Establecimiento |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| Youssef  | David     | 11111111 | Tucuman   | UTN             |
| Youssef  | Guadalupe | 22222222 | San Juan  | EAS             |
| Youssef  | Miguel    | 33333333 |           |                 |
| Youssef  | Facundo   | 444444   |           | ROSSO           |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Teniendo en cuenta que en la tabla users_info_data no todos los userid estan asociados a todos los fieldid.
Usé la siguiente consulta, pero no me da el resultado esperado:

```sql
SELECT
  u.firstname as nombre,
  IF(udata.fieldid=1,udata.data,'-') as dni,
  IF(udata.fieldid=2,udata.data,'-') as provincia,
  IF(udata.fieldid=3,udata.data,'-') as establecimiento
FROM
  users_info_data udata
JOIN
  users u
ON
  u.id = udata.userid
JOIN
  users_info_fields ufield
ON
  ufield.id = udata.fieldid
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: Has intentado usar `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer una selección de cada valor condicionando por el `fileid` mediante un `case when ...` o bien el el `IF`, aunque la primer forma es más compatible con el ansi SQL. Con esto logras que cada valor ocupe la columna deseada, lo que restaría es obtener una sola fila por `usuario` y ahí entra la agrupación, es necesario usar una función de agregación como `MAX` en las nueva columnas:

```
SELECT u.lastname as apellido,
       u.firstname as nombre,
       IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ud.fieldid=1 THEN ud.data ELSE NULL END), '-') as DNI,
       IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ud.fieldid=2 THEN ud.data ELSE NULL END), '-') as Provincia,
       IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ud.fieldid=3 THEN ud.data ELSE NULL END), '-') as Establecimiento
       FROM users u
       LEFT JOIN users_info_data ud
           ON ud.userid = u.id
       GROUP BY u.lastname,
                u.firstname
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero es que la tabla **users_info_fields** esta sobrando ya que estas usando el valor escribiendo manualmente.

Ahora para tener ese resultado solo usa una *subconsulta*

```
SELECT u.firstname as nombre,
(SELECT udata.data FROM users_info_data udata WHERE udata.fieldid=1 AND udata.userid=u.id)  as dni,
(SELECT udata.data FROM users_info_data udata WHERE udata.fieldid=2 AND udata.userid=u.id) as provincia,
(SELECT udata.data FROM users_info_data udata WHERE udata.fieldid=3 AND udata.userid=u.id) as establecimiento
FROM users u;
```

Igual es una de las tantas soluciones, de igual manera te dejo un ejemplo practico para que uses y realices pruebas

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbe992/1